# Valgrind reports errors only when built with Sanitizers

Tags: c++, valgrind, address-sanitizer

While working on one open source project, I performed a build in two ways:

1. Cmake Debug Build with sanitizers enabled(Address, Memory, Thread, UB).
2. Regular Cmake Debug build.

This is running on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine off of Parallels.

When running `valgrind --leak-check=full <execute all unit tests>`, **Case 1**, first gives the warning `==25464== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x8f21000, 0x24c75000) (defined)` and then shows thousands of errors with a single error statement `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)`.
On the other hand Case 2 shows 0 errors.

I'm not sure whether this is a legitimate problem or something introduced due to the sanitizers added? More details [here](https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/issues/4439)

Comment: I don't think a sanitizer build is supposed to run with valgrind (memcheck). It's basically two similar tools trying to do the same things and stepping on each other.

Comment: So, if Valgrind doesnt report errors in Case 2 and the sanitizers dont report problems, I can be sure that this is an artifact introduced due to the sanitizers and no problem in the code itself?

Comment: Debug build (without Sanitizers) tends to initialize to zero uninitialized memory.

Comment: @Jarod42 Im sorry I didnt fully get what you meant and its implications?

Comment: Not familiar with Valgrind and sanitizer (So cannot say if case 1 is real error or false positive), but default behavior of debug build (implicit initialization of variable/buffer to 0) might hide code error(case 2). So code might have a problem even if not detected in case 2.

Comment: I did not know that(implicit zero init in debug builds) - is there some reference you could point me to where I could read more about this? Also then a simple way to check against it is to run valgrind against a release build?

Comment: Sorry, don't have reference, quick search give value from Msvc which are not zero ([when-and-why-will-an-os-initialise-memory-to-0xcd-0xdd-etc-on-malloc-free-new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370195/when-and-why-will-an-os-initialise-memory-to-0xcd-0xdd-etc-on-malloc-free-new)) or vague explanation ([why-are-local-variables-initialized-to-0-in-g-compiler-for-c-in-ubuntu-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143354/why-are-local-variables-initialized-to-0-in-g-compiler-for-c-in-ubuntu-linux))

Comment: @Jarod42 "Debug build tends to initialize to zero uninitialized memory" - this is a very strong statement, please provide prooflinks.